# My SQL error:too many connections

Tags: mysql, connection

My website has been showing an error related to database.

The error says- Warning:mysql_connect()[function.mysql-connect]:Too many connections in /home/host1/public_html/www.mysite.com/db_connection.php on line 2.Could not connect error.Too many connections.

I get the error occasionally, but when i refresh the page say after 20 seconds the error disappears and page appear normally. I tried to rectify this by putting a code to close the sql connection after the page finishes loading. But even after that i got this error. Can you tell we what could possibly be wrong. Is it a server issue or is it related to my code?

Comment: What is your max connections set to?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check:

Are you using mysql_pconnect to connect to the database? This will make a persistent connection that remains open once it is established and will re-use that connection instead of creating a new db connection each time.

Also check max_connections and max_user_connections in the my.cnf file as you may be reaching a limit set in those two variables.

Comment: Thanks Shaun for the reply..I am not using the persistent connection. So there is no chance of an error through the first case. And i am using shared hosting account and not a dedicated server.So do i have the privilege to access the my.cnf file in shared hosting service...

Answer (score 2):

If you run this query:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

You will see what all connections are currently up, and what they are doing.  This should give you a better idea as to what is holding things up.  Over time, connections can get stuck, and it is possible they can sit there for a long time.  More likely though, you have a hacked script (or poorly written script causing a lot of locks).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brad...I tried the command just after opening multiple tabs.Result was time:0 state:null. Also i am using connection close command at end of page...Hope that that works and the error dont appear again...About the script i don't think i am using too complex scripts on my page. My Site is www.kochiservnet.com.

Comment: You ran `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`?  You should have been given a list of running queries...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not closing the connection in your php script.
Using **mysql_close()**, which explicitly closes the connections. The use of mysql_close() in conjunction with mysql_connect() would ensure that the connection is closed.

Comment: The connection is always closed at the end of the script, automatically.  While I agree, it is good practice to explicitly call `mysql_close()`, I doubt that is the issue here.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the reply.I closed the connections in all pages.I have read that, by default the connection closes when the page load is complete. But still i gave a connection close statement at the end...of all pages....The problem is that the error occurance is for only few seconds 20-30 seconds.after that i refresh the page...its back to normal...

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully close connections after querys are finished then try upping max_connections in my.cnf.

MySQL administrator in their [GUI-tools package](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) might give you an idea as to what is happening.

Comment: I dont think i have the privilege to access the my.cnf file with the shared hosting account i am using.I get about 200 hits/day. But i dont think that isn't something a server from hostgator cant handle...I contacted hostgator live chat. they say that they cant trouble shoot the error unless they see it live.My prob error goes after 20-40 sec after it appear...By the time i contact them and gets a analyst the error disappears... :-(. I show them screen shot and error text....Still no help.... :-(